# how to change the colour and text continuously? (GUI, Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, tk-toolkit

I've written code(in the image), but my job is changing them continuously. which means I should use for or while loop(I guess) but I don't know how to fix it. :(

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title('Changer')
change_color = False

def change_colour():
      global change_color
      if not change_color:
            change_color = True
            label.config(bg = 'red', text = 'WRONG')
      else:
            label.config(bg = 'green', text = 'RIGHT')
      
label = Label(window, text = '', font = ('Arial', 50), bg = 'grey', width = 10)
label.pack()
button = Button(window, text = 'press', width = 15, command = change_colour)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don’t see any code, can you paste the actual text from the code?

Comment: sorry. I just edited!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to change the background colour each time the user presses the button. Here's a way to do that:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title('Changer')

def change_colour():
      if label.cget('bg') == 'green':
            label.config(bg = 'red', text = 'WRONG')
      else:
            label.config(bg = 'green', text = 'RIGHT')
      
label = Label(window, text = '', font = ('Arial', 50), bg = 'grey', width = 10)
label.pack()
button = Button(window, text = 'press', width = 15, command = change_colour)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Initially the background is the default grey. Pressing the button will change it to green, then pressing it again will turn it red. It will then alternate between green/red.

If you want it to be red on the first click, replace the `if` line with this:

```py
if label.cget('bg') != 'red':
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Can I ask what 'cget' means? in the 'if' statement? I've learnt 'get' function but haven't seen 'cget' before

Comment: You're welcome! It's a way to get the options for the control. It's equivalent to `label['bg']`, but you could also get all the other things such as `label['width']`, `label['text']` and so on. You can also use this to set individual options as well, like so: `label['bg'] = 'red'`

Comment: aha I got it. so it is for picking specific parameter up? so like if I want to change based on width, then I can write 'if label.cget('width') == 10:. then it will only change when width is set with 10 do I understand right?